# Comparing DateTime in Entity Framework with an Sql Server Compact database

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-sql

Why this code throws a `System.NotSupportedException` telling that `The specified method 'int? DateDiff(string, DateTime?, DateTime?)' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression`, though DateDiff has EdmFunction attribute?

```
context.Users.Where(f => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second", f.LastLogOn, somedatetime) < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete enumeration of canonical Date and Time functions supported by Entity SQL query provider [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx).

Try something like this

```
context.Users.Where(f=>EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(f.LastLogOn, somedatetime)<0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is SqlCe not Sql Server, it does not support any compare functions other than DateDiff.

Comment: As far as I understand this function will be translated into DateDiff. Give it a try :)

Comment: For the Entity Framework version 6, consider to use `DbFunctions.DiffSeconds`