# Using DateDiff in Entity Framework on a SQL CE database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I have a method which should return a list of anonymous objects with a calculated column like this:

```
        var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        return from t in this.Events
                where (t.StartTime >= DateTime.Today && t.StartTime < tomorrow && t.EndTime.HasValue)
                select new
                {
                    Client = t.Activity.Project.Customer.Name,
                    Project = t.Activity.Project.Name,
                    Task = t.Activity.Task.Name,
                    Rate = t.Activity.Rate.Name,
                    StartTime = t.StartTime,
                    EndTime = t.EndTime.Value,
                    Hours = (System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("m", t.StartTime, t.EndTime.Value) / 60),
                    Description = t.Activity.Description
                };
```

Unfortunately I get the following error from the DateDiff function:

**The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiff(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression**.

Any ideas what I could have done wrong here?

EDIT: I also tried the EntityFunctions class mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174831/comparing-datetime-in-entity-framework-with-an-sql-server-compact-database), but that did not work as well.

```
Minutes = EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(t.EndTime, t.StartTime),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit]

```
Hours = (System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mi", t.StartTime, t.EndTime.Value) / 60)
```

is not supported SQL CE.

```
Hours = ((TimeSpan)(t.EndTime.Value - t.StartTime)).TotalHours
```

Throws an DbArithmeticExpression Exception

So, I think you'll have to do it in two steps. Grab the data you need, then calculate the time difference in memory.

```
var events = (from t in context.Events
    where (t.StartTime >= DateTime.Today && t.StartTime < tomorrow && t.EndTime.HasValue)
    select t).ToArray();

return from t in events
    select new
    {
         ...
         Hours = (t.EndTime.Value - t.StartTime).TotalHours
    };
```

Comment: This is what I started off with, and it could not be translated. So I searched and the recommended approach was to use SqlFunctions.

Comment: With this code, I get the exception: **DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.**

Comment: TotalHours is not defined by linq2EF, It's better just have your edited answer :)

Comment: I had already implemented this way, but I'll accept this for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the EF provider to handle the DATEDIFF in SQL, which I don't think is possible in any version of SQL.  Use native DateTime functions:

```
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        return from t in this.Events
                where (t.StartTime >= DateTime.Today && t.StartTime < tomorrow && t.EndTime.HasValue)
                select new
                {
                    Client = t.Activity.Project.Customer.Name,
                    Project = t.Activity.Project.Name,
                    Task = t.Activity.Task.Name,
                    Rate = t.Activity.Rate.Name,
                    StartTime = t.StartTime,
                    EndTime = t.EndTime.Value,
                    Hours = t.EndTime.Value(t.StartTime.Subtract).Hours,
                    Description = t.Activity.Description
                };
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your response. I tried `Hours = t.EndTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartTime)` and I got the error message **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: EF is still trying to translate into T-SQL.  You will probably have to get the resultset without the datediff and then project it into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities, remove Value from EndTime:

```
Hours = (System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("m", t.StartTime, t.EndTime) / 60)
```

Or use DateDiffHour:

```
Hours = (System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiffHour(t.StartTime, t.EndTime)
```

Comment: Hi Shahid! Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the first option gives me the same error message. And the second, well, there is no such method "DateDiffHour".

Comment: The DateDiffHour method reference can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495790.aspx
But it may not supported by CE framework.

Otherwise I would prefer to handle dates within C# code, instead of SQL specific, as mentioned by @Steven Kimpe.